# Is centripetal acceleration around an ellipse with constant tangential velocity always pointed towards the center of the ellipse?

Tags: physics, acceleration

I've tried to find answers online but surprisingly couldn't find any.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is purely a Physics question

Comment: Work out the force vectors for yourself!  Just look at the instantaneous velocity vector and the direction of acceleration required to stay on the elliptical path.

Comment: It's not even a physics question. It's purely mathematics.

Comment: I suggest to re-ask your question on the https://physics.stackexchange.com . This site is only for space exploration things.

Comment: It's a cool exercise but it's not on-topic here. You could consider asking in [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or Physics SE as mentioned above (may be a better fit) but no matter where you ask it you'll need to make some effort to solve it yourself and explain where and why you are stuck.